# Android Live Wallpapers for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, android, desktop-customization

Is it possible to have Android live wallpapers on Windows 7?

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is called 'Dreamscene'. It used to be a part of windows but was later turned off. There are several websites that offer little applications for free to turn it back on. Then you can set any video that Windows Media Player can use as the wallpaper.

I am not linking to any of these sites as I would not be surprised that some have crapware/malware what not.

[Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_DreamScene)

Comment: There are workarounds for Dreamscene, apparently. But I've never tried them http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/01/14/how-to-install-and-enable-dreamscene-in-windows-7/

Comment: I wrote a tutorial for using live wallpapers in Windows 7 with DreamScene. [How To Use Videos As Live Wallpapers in Windows XP, Vista or 7](http://tutznet.com/videos-live-wallpapers-windows-xp-vista-7.html)

Answer (score 1):

A good software that is along the lines of what you are looking for (but not from Android) is **Desktop Earth**.  It's dynamic, and pretty cool!  Have used myself, seems to be clean...

> http://codefromthe70s.org/desktopearth_dl.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Dreamscene was good but consumed a lot of system recources.

If you are running and older system like dual core or earlier, better not use it and I don't think Dreamscene works on Windows 7. Why not try out [live rotating earth wallpaper for windows](http://www.codefromthe70s.org/desktopearth.aspx) instead.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few options available for some kind of active wallpaper.

1. The best option is to write a program or script that creates the right kind of window, but this is beyond the scope of most people's interests. If you're not intimidated by programming, this offers the most flexibility and efficiency and least cost. I've seen it done in Python with a few hundred lines of code.
2. There is a Free Open-Source program called Lively that facilitates adding most things (image, video, web page, Unity Engine Game/Application, etc) as your desktop background. Its features are not as broad as some paid programs, and it's not quite as efficient.
3. There is a cheap ($4-$5 USD) program called Wallpaper Engine that offers more features and better performance than Lively. There are other paid wallpaper programs as well.

You'll need to experiment with each option to find out which one suits your particular purposes.